Mongoose auto complete not working in controller files
When i try to write moongoose in controllers file auto complete not working but when i try this in models file working fine
Side note:i have one more project and auto complete working great at this project mongoose versions are same, same vscode, same extensions.
what i did ?

I  try add type of mongoose -> yarn add @types/mongoose
Checked extension like i said at other project working fine there is something different

And Yes api working


